# Using BigQuery to connect Goggle sheets to Power BI

Tags: google-sheets, google-bigquery, powerbi

I am trying to have a live connection from google sheet to Power BI. Unfortunately, I could not find a simpler way to do so without compromising security. BigQuery seems a good solution since it will connect to both.

I have no experience with BigQuery or SQL. I was able to connect my sheet to BigQuery. However, I was not able to push it to power BI properly. I have one line query to select table from google sheets and when I save the results and connect to Power BI the data will not update if changes happen to the google sheets.

Could you please give me some guidance on the matter and if it is possible. I am testing this in my personal account and if this works I will implement on my work corporate google account.

Comment: Big Query is designed for massive levels of data, unless your sheet is in the multi gigabyte range it's over kill.

Comment: I understand that it is an overkill but could you please offer guidance on the matter.

Comment: Can you update the question with updates 'live connection'? is this real time?. What are the security issues? and other requirements, to give it some context so you can get a recommendation